# using date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['original_date'])) changes the order of dates in bootstrap table

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, date, mysqli

My code is the below. The column type for saving dates in database is DATE. The problem is that if i put `$row['appointment_date']`  the table shows the dates in order as YYYY-mm-dd, but if i put `date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['appointment_date']))` to show the dates in the format i want `(dd-mm-YYYY)`, then the order changes and shows dates in order by day but not by month and year. For example it shows 02-05-2011, 03-03-2011, 05-01-2011 etc. I have also tried `DateTime::createFromFormat` but the problem still exists. Using the default date format the output is this[default_date_format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCf3C.png).But using the format d-m-Y the output is this [without_default_date_format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6U8X.png)

```
<?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM appointment,users WHERE appointment.user_id=users.user_id AND users.role_id=2 ORDER BY appointment.appointment_date";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['appointment_date'])); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo substr($row['appointment_time'],0,5); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['appointment_notes']; ?></td>
       </tr>
        <?php
         }
?>
```

Comment: Try using the default date format and then show me the output. It seems that the problem is not with the d-m-Y

Comment: try using ORDER BY appointment.appointment_date ASC"; or ORDER BY appointment.appointment_date DESC"; in your query

Comment: with the default date format the order is ok. it shows 2018-08-10,2018-08-16,2018-09-20 etc

Comment: Format the date when you output the data. The database is for storing values, the UI is for displaying them. Maintain the separation of duties and your world will be easier.

Comment: The order that the data comes out of the database is **not** affected by how the data subsequently gets displayed. Somewhere in the bootstrap code your table is being sorted after you create it. Unfortunately I don't know enough about bootstrap to say where/why that might be. I will tag your question with `twitter-bootstrap` so hopefully someone with that knowledge can help.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 ORDER BY appointment.appointment_date ASC";
```

or

```
 ORDER BY appointment.appointment_date DESC";
```

in your query ...

If you don't specify the ASC or DESC keyword, ASC or ascending order is by default.

so when you use yyyy-mm-dd, it is ascending by yyyy and when you use dd-mm-yyyy, it is ascending by dd. so specify asc or desc in query...

so your query should be

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM appointment,users WHERE appointment.user_id=users.user_id AND users.role_id=2 ORDER BY appointment.appointment_date DESC";
```

Updated :

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM appointment,users WHERE appointment.user_id=users.user_id AND users.role_id=2 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(appointment.appointment_date , '%Y-%m-%d') ASC";
```

Comment: i've specified with ASC but i still have the same problem as shown in the link.

Comment: please check for updated query in answer at bottom and try with it

Comment: i've also tried that but i don't have problem when the format is Y-m-d.In that case the order is ok.The problem is when my date format is d-m-Y

Comment: basically it is not related to echo date(d-m-Y... it is sure..... it is related to your query only....